# How to insert data to table from differences between this table and other one, using genereted sequence id?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle12c

I have two tables and I try to insert rows from `SECOND_TABLE` to `FIRST_TABLE`.

I create two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE FIRST_TABLE(
    F_ID NUMBER(10) not null,
    F_NAME VARCHAR(8 BYTE) not null,
    F_DESCRIPTION NVARCHAR2(1000) not null
  );


  CREATE TABLE SECOND_TABLE(
    S_ID NUMBER(10) not null,
    S_NAME VARCHAR(8 BYTE) not null,
    S_DESCRIPTION NVARCHAR2(1000) not null
  );
```

I found differences between `SECOND_TABLE` and `FIRST_TABLE`:

`select S_NAME,S_DESCRIPTION from SECOND_TABLE minus select F_NAME,F_DESCRIPTION from FIRST_TABLE;`

I create a statement:

`insert into FIRST_TABLE F_ID,F_NAME,F_DESCRIPTION (select * from SECOND_TABLE where not exists (select * from FIRST_TABLE where SECOND_TABLE.S_NAME = FIRST_TABLE.F_NAME));`

but this statement copy `F_ID`, I don't have idea how to change this statement to not copy `F_ID`, but generate it from sequence `CSS_F`. It should looks like:

`insert into FIRST_TABLE (F_ID) values (CSS_F.nextval);`

Could you give me an advice how to add inserting genereted id to this statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the name and description columns from the second_table and use the sequence for inserting the F_ID column.

```
insert into FIRST_TABLE (F_ID,F_NAME,F_DESCRIPTION)
select CSS_F.nextval, S_NAME, S_DESCRIPTION
from SECOND_TABLE S
where not exists (select * from FIRST_TABLE where S.S_NAME = F_NAME)
```